# Reducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let's look at this example: $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2+2)$. The polynomial $f(x)=x^2+2$ is reducible because $f(1)=0$. What should we say about the ring $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2+2)$?

Comment: Of course this is a ring. But it has zero divisors.

Comment: If $F_3[x]/(x^2+2)$ denotes the quotient ring modulo the ideal generated by $x^2+2$, it's certainly a ring. What else? Maybe your question is if it's a field. Please, formulate your question more clearly: the same symbol can't denote two different things.

Comment: thank you. i really messed up

Comment: it is a ring and written in the question.

Comment: the elements are 2x+2,2x+1,2x,x+2,x+1,x,2,1,0. am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In $\Bbb F_3[x]$ you have the identity:
$$
(x+1)(x+2)=x^2+2.
$$
Note that the linear forms $(x+1)$ and $(x+2)$ are coprime in $\Bbb F_3[x]$. So by the [Chinese Reminder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) this leads to a conclusion:
$$
\Bbb F_3[x]/(x^2+2)\simeq \Bbb F_3[x]/(x+1)\times \Bbb F_3[x]/(x+2)\simeq \Bbb F_3\times \Bbb F_3
$$
where the last isomorphism is induced by a product of evaluation maps, first at point $-1=2$ then at $1=-2$.